# An error occurred: python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully

Tags: python

When I am trying to install detectron2 and fvcore with pip, for example, execute the command: pip3.9 install fvcore. An error occurred: python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully. The complete error is as follows:
——————————————————————————————————————————

```
        root@gky-System-Product-Name:\~# pip3.9 install fvcore
        Collecting fvcore
        Using cached fvcore-0.1.5.post20221221.tar.gz (50 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
        Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/gky/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fvcore) (1.26.2)
        Collecting yacs\>=0.1.6 (from fvcore)
        Using cached yacs-0.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
        Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml\>=5.1 in /home/gky/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyYAML-6.0.1-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg (from fvcore) (6.0.1)
        Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /home/gky/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fvcore) (4.66.1)
        Collecting termcolor\>=1.1 (from fvcore)
        Using cached termcolor-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.1 kB)
        Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /home/gky/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fvcore) (10.1.0)
        Collecting tabulate (from fvcore)
        Using cached tabulate-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
        Collecting iopath\>=0.1.7 (from fvcore)
        Using cached iopath-0.1.10.tar.gz (42 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
        Requirement already satisfied: typing_extensions in /home/gky/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from iopath\>=0.1.7-\>fvcore) (4.8.0)
        Collecting portalocker (from iopath\>=0.1.7-\>fvcore)
        Using cached portalocker-2.8.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.5 kB)
        Using cached termcolor-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.7 kB)
        Using cached portalocker-2.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
        Building wheels for collected packages: fvcore, iopath
        Building wheel for fvcore (setup.py) ... error
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
        × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─\> \[6 lines of output\]
        usage: setup.py \[global_opts\] cmd1 \[cmd1_opts\] \[cmd2 \[cmd2_opts\] ...\]
        or: setup.py --help \[cmd1 cmd2 ...\]
        or: setup.py --help-commands
        or: setup.py cmd --help

              error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
              [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for fvcore
        Running setup.py clean for fvcore
        Building wheel for iopath (setup.py) ... error
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─\> \[6 lines of output\]
        usage: setup.py \[global_opts\] cmd1 \[cmd1_opts\] \[cmd2 \[cmd2_opts\] ...\]
        or: setup.py --help \[cmd1 cmd2 ...\]
        or: setup.py --help-commands
        or: setup.py cmd --help

              error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
              [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for iopath
        Running setup.py clean for iopath
        Failed to build fvcore iopath
        ERROR: Could not build wheels for fvcore, iopath, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

——————————————————————————————————————————

The setup.py of python3.9 has been added:

```
import setuptools
from setuptools import setup, Extension
```

I have upgraded wheel and setuptools before, But it still prompts bdist_wheel...

——————————————————————————————————————————

```
root@gky-System-Product-Name:/home/gky/opt/Python-3.9.0# pip3.9 install wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /home/gky/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.42.0)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behavior with the system package managa virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
root@gky-System-Product-Name:/home/gky/opt/Python-3.9.0# pip3.9 install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/gky/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (69.0.3)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behavior with the system package managa virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

——————————————————————————————————————————

Please tell me what should I do to solve this problem?